# Make mouse click on right edge of screen act on scroll bar

Tags: mouse, scrollbar

In `firefox`, if I move my mouse to **extreme** right of the screen and do left click, the scroll bar will respond to this click. But this function does not hold for all applications. Is there any possible way to bring this function to other applications?

In fact, what I need is to achieve this function in `Foxit Reader`. Instead of adopting the system window style, `Foxit Reader` has its own UI, so I think simply change the desktop theme may not help and some tweak with X-server will be needed. By the way, I am using ubuntu 20.04 with gnome.

Comment: Are there any more applications that show this undesired behaviour?

Comment: @vanadium That depends on the desktop theme, since `firefox` also uses its own UI, it admits such feature under any theme. However, `gnome-terminal`, for example, also behave the same as `firefox` under ubuntu default theme `Yaru`.